# Loading external HTML page with relative paths into a DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, relative-path, jquery-load, relative-url

I am relatively new to jQuery and pardon if this question is too simple, but I've searched numerous threads for hours and cannot find a definite solution.

I have the following folder structure:

```
/index.html

/html/pages/page1.html
/html/pages/images/
/html/pages/css/
/html/pages/js/
/html/pages/includes/
```

I am trying to load **page1.html** into a DIV in **index.html** in the following basic way:

```
$('#content').load('html/pages/page1.html', function () {
   console.log('loaded');
});
```

**page1.html** loads fine, however, it consists of multiple includes and all the content in it (images, CSS, JS, etc.) is relative to the **pages** folder (for example: ../images/header.jpg), so it does not show when loaded into **index.html** since now everything becomes relative to **/** or **index.html**.

I read somewhere that making all paths absolute or root relative in **page1.html** will work, also adding sort of a global path variable, however, the PROBLEM is that there is too much legacy content and changing all of it is not an option.

Is there a way to do load **page1.html** as described above without modifying any of the paths, despite that they're relative? Or can someone recommend an efficient way (other plugins, techniques) of loading external content this way?

Thank you!

Comment: In case you just want to load the html page, you can load it using iframe too. The relative path defined in page1.html stays with respect to pages in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything **is relative to** the `pages` folder, then you can use some simple searching and replacing. This isn't the best programming practice, as it is not as flexible (going from relative to absolute in this type of context is relying on a number of factors working properly) as it should be, but it will work.

```
$.get('html/pages/page1.html', {}, function(data, status, xhr) {
    var updatedData = data.replace(/\.\.\/(images|css|js)+/g, "http://www.mywebsite.com/html/$1");

    $('#content').html(updatedData);
});
```

#### Edit:

You could also use a proxy script and rewrite/route all requests to this folder to the proxy script. I don't know what server-side technology you are using, but you could do this:

Using `.htaccess` (or the like), redirect all requests directed to this folder to another script in your codebase. In the script, look for the path that is incoming to the script, load the original output contents, perform a search/replace and output the contents to the buffer. In addition, you can set up caching on the server so that the client would cache the requests lowering the processing overhead that you might experience (though, I would anticipate that to be fairly minimal).

Comment: I thought about something like this,but the problem is that there is also a lot of content in separate CSS files, mostly background images, as well as some paths, (for Flash content) embedded in JavaScript. That's why I'm stuck.

Comment: I could help with PHP, but unfortunately not JSP. I did give the general framework idea for how to implement this.

Comment: So for the most part I figured that using .load() in a standard way will not really work in my instance. I have to either use your recommendation as a workaround or maybe consider using iframes or a third party library such as graybox. Thank you for looking into this. I'll accept your answer.